# IE8 crashing after browsing a site for a few minutes

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, crash, windbg

All,

I've a problem with a site I coded. It works fine under other browsers, but IE8 crashes after clicking around a few times. It doesn't show any error message, just crashes.

I attached WinDbg and made a dump when it crashed. When analyzing the dump WinDbg show this:

```
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(e58.1fa8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=06c00050 edx=00000000 esi=06c00050 edi=06c00050
eip=3cf07b98 esp=016cdb38 ebp=016cdc48 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00210246
mshtml!CDoc::OnUrlImgCtxChange+0x242:
3cf07b98 8b4308          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebx+8] ds:0023:00000008=????????
0:008> .ecxr
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=06c00050 edx=00000000 esi=06c00050 edi=06c00050
eip=3cf07b98 esp=016cdb38 ebp=016cdc48 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00210246
mshtml!CDoc::OnUrlImgCtxChange+0x242:
3cf07b98 8b4308          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebx+8] ds:0023:00000008=????????
```

Not sure if this is connected with JS, but I'm using jquery 1.6.2, jquery.fancybox 1.3.4, jquery.orbit 1.2.3, cufon, modernizr 2.0 and HTML5 Boilerplate.[1].

Any idea what it might be or what do try next?

Comment: Well, you can't fix bugs in IE8 so I don't know what use it will be to debug it.

Comment: I didn't either. But I was hoping someone smarter then me can find it useful. Anyway, it seems I found a solution - see my response

Comment: It seems it's a jquery bug. This question/answer describes it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828214/jquery-1-6-2-crashes-ie8-tabs/

Comment: What OS was this issue encountered on?

Comment: It was on Windows XP SP3. Updating JQuery to a newer version fixed it. The cause was as described in the bug from my prev comment. Stackoverflow converted my answer to a comment, so I couldn't accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put my own comment as an answer:

This was caused by a JQuery bug [#9823](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9823)

See [this other question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828214/jquery-1-6-2-crashes-ie8-tabs/) for more details.