# jQuery Tabs Require Refresh to Load in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-tabs

In IE8, and only IE8, my tabs are not created until the first postback or refresh.  I'm betting someone else has experienced this, and knows of a workaround.  I'm using

jquery-1.7.1.min.js, 
jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js

It's this simple:

```
  // Tabs
    $tabs = $('#tab-control');

    // hide them until all logic and elements are wired up and ready ...
    //
    $tabs.hide();
    $tabs.tabs();

    $tabs.bind( "tabsselect", function(e, ui) {
    console.log('Setting cookie [' + cookieName + '] with value ' + ui.index + '...');
        $.cookies.set(cookieName, ui.index);
    });

    stickyTab = $.cookies.get(cookieName);

    if( ! isNaN( stickyTab ) ) {
        console.log('Now selecting tab: ' + stickyTab + '.');
        $tabs.tabs('select', stickyTab);
    }

    $tabs.show(300);
```

Check it out for yourself (please use IE8): http://senchaportfolios.com

Dan

Comment: Possible duplicate with [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828214/jquery-1-6-2-crashes-ie8-tabs)?

Comment: Don't think so.  Plus, I already read the post your are referring to and its comments.  There, the author states that his tabs are crashed upon refresh.  Mine are actually working upon refresh.  In fact, refreshing the page is the workaround for this issue.  However, I cannot expect the user to refresh the page.